# create new data frame based on two different data frame in python using loop function

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

I am new to python, could anyone help me on the below?
I have two data frames (DF1 & DF2) like below,

```
DF1:
project_ID  dataID#
AAA         dataset_01
BBB         dataset_02
CCC         dataset_01
DDD         dataset_02

DF2:
dataID#     Items
dataset_01  Apple
dataset_01  Orange
dataset_02  banana
dataset_02  Grape
```

Each `dataID` has list of `Items`.
Basically i want to create new data frame to list the `Items` (from DF2) based on the `dataID#` for each project_ID (from DF1)
I want to have the output something like below (new data frame (DF3)) something like this,

```
project_ID  dataID#      Items
AAA         dataset_01   Apple
AAA         dataset_01   Orange
BBB         dataset_02   banana
BBB         dataset_02   Grape
CCC         dataset_01   Apple
CCC         dataset_01   Orange
DDD         dataset_02   banana
DDD         dataset_02   Grape
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge the data.frames using [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
import pandas as pd
DF1 = pd.DataFrame({'project_ID':['AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD'],
                    'dataID':['dataset_01','dataset_02','dataset_01','dataset_02']})

DF2 = pd.DataFrame({'dataID':['dataset_01','dataset_01','dataset_02','dataset_02'],
                    'Items':['Apple','Orange','banana','Grape']})

DF1.merge(DF2)


project_ID  dataID  Items
0   AAA dataset_01  Apple
1   AAA dataset_01  Orange
2   CCC dataset_01  Apple
3   CCC dataset_01  Orange
4   BBB dataset_02  banana
5   BBB dataset_02  Grape
6   DDD dataset_02  banana
7   DDD dataset_02  Grape
```